# What effect does voltage have on electron energy levels?

Tags: electricity, electrons

Is there any effect at all on an electron's energy level when subjected to a voltage?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stark_effect

Comment: In metals and semiconductors an electric field will tilt the band structure, which gets electrons "moving".

Comment: If it is a free electron inside the acceleration region of an electron gun the only state it has is momentum - and the voltage increases the momentum (and kinetic energy).  This is a continuum state.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows insufficient research effort. "Voltage" means electric fields and electric fields + energy levels leads you directly to the stark effect.

Comment: @Martin Although to be fair, "Stark effect" isn't something I'd know to Google if I didn't already know about it.

Comment: I'm voting to **leave open** because "insufficient effort" is not, nor ever has been, a reason to close. That's what the downvote button is for.